# JS Вызов асинхронной функции с возвратом результата

Tags: javascript, async-await, асинхронность

Тестовый вопрос

```js
const b = async () => {  return 10; }

let c = await b;
console.log(c)
```

Как получить результат 10 из асинхронной функции ? Не понимаю, почему не происходит возврат.

Comment: И что собственно не происходит?

Comment: ожидал, что в консоль попадет 10. Но, этого не происходит. Вопрос - почему. Как получить в консоль результат выполнения асинхронной функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - это нужно функцию вызывать. Т.е. у ее имени должны быть круглые скобки - `b()`.

> Как получить результат 10 из асинхронной функции ?

Вот так

```js
const b = async () => {  return 10; }

b()
  .then(c => console.log(c))
  .catch(console.log)
```

> Не понимаю, почему не происходит возврат.

Использовать `await` можно только в `async` функциях

```js
const b = async () => {  return 10; }

(async _ => {
  let c = await b();
  console.log(c)
})()
```

Comment: Спасибо, так стало понятнее.