# JS Получение результата значение Promise из функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

Задача по дополнению к [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495814/js-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment2681836_1495814). По получению данных из асинхронных функций.

```js
let a = new Promise( () => { return 10; } );

a().then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Вопрос, как вернуть значение 10 ?

Comment: `const a = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(10));  a.then((value) => console.log(value));`

Comment: Вернуть 10 кому?

Comment: [https://learn.javascript.ru/promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) или на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)- Для начала, лучше ознакомиться с теорией, что бы лучше понимать, как это работает

Comment: Ещё раз дам ссылку на самый популярный вопрос ruSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как вернуть значение 10 ?

Первое - `a` промис, не функция. Ей круглые скобки не нужны.

Второе - промисы нужно завершать. Есть два варианта завершения "успех" или "не успех".

Если все успешно - нужно вызвать функцию `resolve` и передать ей нужное значение. В случае не успеха - нужно вызвать функцию `reject` и передать ей нужное значение.

```js
let a = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolve(10) );

a.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```